# Get publisher confirmation for single message

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq

I have a producer which will enqueue whenever a message is received via an API call, and I want to return only when I have confirmation that the message was received by the broker.

I found out how to do this via publisher confirms -

```
    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using(var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchangeName, "topic", true, false, null);
                    //This enables producer confirm
                    channel.ConfirmSelect();

                    var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();

                    properties.Persistent = true;

                    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

                    channel.BasicPublish(exchangeName, topic, properties, body);

                    channel.WaitForConfirms();                         

                    Console.WriteLine("I sent a message !", message);
                }
            }
```

My issue is that I don't want to wait for ALL confirms, just the ones tied to this particular message. I don't want to restrict this to a single thread/worker, and I don't want to wait for everything to confirm.

The rabbit library for js works with a callback which is perfect for my use - but the C# version doesn't seem to support it.

Answer (score 1):

> My issue is that I don't want to wait for ALL confirms, just the ones tied to this particular message.

You should subscribe to the `BasicAcks` callback and use that to correlate confirmations to messages you have published.

> I don't want to restrict this to a single thread/worker

You can share that connection among threads, but you will have to create a per-thread `IModel` instance.

Comment: How about isolating those messages you want in a separate transaction and trying

WaitForConfirms?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [Publisher Confirms](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/02/10/introducing-publisher-confirms/) and Transactions.

Separate the Message You want the Confirmation for into a single (or a subset) of transactions.

The transaction:

```
ch.txSelect(); <-- start transaction
ch.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME,
                            MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_BASIC,
                            "nop".getBytes());
ch.txCommit();<--commit transaction
```

You can use the Streaming Lightweight Publisher Confirms, using:

```
ch.setConfirmListener(new ConfirmListener() {
    public void handleAck(long seqNo, boolean multiple) {

if (multiple) {
    unconfirmedSet.headSet(seqNo+1).clear();
} else {
unconfirmedSet.remove(seqNo);
}
}
    public void handleNack(long seqNo, boolean multiple) {
        // handle the lost messages somehow
    }
```

I hope it helps